# Раскодировать HEX JS код

Tags: javascript

Знатоки, помогите вернуть это дело в нормальный вид

```
var _0x4cf6=["\x6A\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79","\x75\x73\x65\x20\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74","\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x4F\x75\x74","\x5B\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x3D\x22\x63\x69\x72\x63\x6C\x65\x2D\x73\x69\x64\x65\x22\x5D","\x73\x6C\x6F\x77","\x64\x65\x6C\x61\x79","\x23\x70\x72\x65\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72","\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65","\x63\x73\x73","\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x6F\x6E","\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x23\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x64","\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x61\x74\x65","\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x49\x6E","\x23\x6C\x6F\x61\x64\x65\x72\x5F\x66\x6F\x72\x6D","\x6E\x69\x63\x65\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74","\x2E\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x64\x2D\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x20\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74","\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73","\x6D\x79\x2D\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65","\x68\x69\x64\x65\x50\x61\x73\x73\x77\x6F\x72\x64","\x23\x70\x61\x73\x73\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x31\x2C\x20\x23\x70\x61\x73\x73\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x32","\x6F\x75\x74\x70\x75\x74","\x76\x61\x6C","\x24\x65\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x2E\x62\x75\x64\x67\x65\x74\x5F\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x72\x20\x73\x70\x61\x6E","\x72\x61\x6E\x67\x65\x73\x6C\x69\x64\x65\x72","\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x5B\x74\x79\x70\x65\x3D\x22\x72\x61\x6E\x67\x65\x22\x5D","\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B","\x70\x72\x65\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x44\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74","\x68\x61\x73\x68","\x74\x6F\x70","\x6F\x66\x66\x73\x65\x74","\x73\x77\x69\x6E\x67","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x61\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x65","\x73\x74\x6F\x70","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C\x2C\x20\x62\x6F\x64\x79","\x61\x5B\x68\x72\x65\x66\x5E\x3D\x22\x23\x22\x5D\x2E\x6D\x6F\x62\x69\x6C\x65\x5F\x62\x74\x6E","\x2E\x63\x64\x2D\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x79\x2D\x6E\x61\x76","\x2E\x63\x64\x2D\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x6C\x61\x79\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74","\x2E\x63\x64\x2D\x70\x72\x69\x6D\x61\x72\x79\x2D\x6E\x61\x76","\x2E\x63\x64\x2D\x6E\x61\x76\x2D\x74\x72\x69\x67\x67\x65\x72","\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65","\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x41\x6E\x69\x6D\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x46\x72\x61\x6D\x65","\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x2D\x6E\x61\x76","\x68\x61\x73\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73","\x61\x64\x64\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73","\x65\x61\x73\x65\x49\x6E\x43\x75\x62\x69\x63","\x66\x61\x64\x65\x2D\x69\x6E","\x76\x65\x6C\x6F\x63\x69\x74\x79","\x73\x70\x61\x6E","\x63\x68\x69\x6C\x64\x72\x65\x6E","\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73","\x77\x65\x62\x6B\x69\x74\x54\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x45\x6E\x64\x20\x6F\x74\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x65\x6E\x64\x20\x6F\x54\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x45\x6E\x64\x20\x6D\x73\x54\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x45\x6E\x64\x20\x74\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x65\x6E\x64","\x69\x73\x2D\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E","\x6F\x6E\x65","\x6E\x6F\x2D\x63\x73\x73\x74\x72\x61\x6E\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73","\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x70\x6F\x77","\x77\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x73\x71\x72\x74","\x70\x78"];(function(_0x5e5bx1){_0x4cf6[1];_0x5e5bx1(window)[_0x4cf6[11]](_0x4cf6[2],function(){_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[4])[_0x4cf6[3]]();_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[7])[_0x4cf6[6]](350)[_0x4cf6[3]](_0x4cf6[5]);_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[10])[_0x4cf6[6]](350)[_0x4cf6[9]]({"\x6F\x76\x65\x72\x66\x6C\x6F\x77":_0x4cf6[8]})});_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[13])[_0x4cf6[11]](_0x4cf6[12],function(){var _0x5e5bx2=_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[13]);_0x5e5bx2[_0x4cf6[14]]();if(_0x5e5bx2[_0x4cf6[15]]()){_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[17])[_0x4cf6[16]]()}});_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[19])[_0x4cf6[18]]();_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[23])[_0x4cf6[22]](_0x4cf6[20],{toggle:{className:_0x4cf6[21]}});_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[30])[_0x4cf6[29]]({polyfill:false,onInit:function(){this[_0x4cf6[24]]= _0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[28])[_0x4cf6[27]](this[_0x4cf6[26]][_0x4cf6[25]]())},onSlide:function(_0x5e5bx3,_0x5e5bx4){this[_0x4cf6[24]][_0x4cf6[27]](_0x5e5bx4)}});_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[41])[_0x4cf6[11]](_0x4cf6[31],function(_0x5e5bx5){_0x5e5bx5[_0x4cf6[32]]();var _0x5e5bx6=this[_0x4cf6[33]];var _0x5e5bx7=_0x5e5bx1(_0x5e5bx6);_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[40])[_0x4cf6[39]]()[_0x4cf6[38]]({"\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x54\x6F\x70":_0x5e5bx7[_0x4cf6[35]]()[_0x4cf6[34]]},400,_0x4cf6[36],function(){window[_0x4cf6[37]][_0x4cf6[33]]= _0x5e5bx6})});var _0x5e5bx8=_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[42]),_0x5e5bx9=_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[43]),_0x5e5bxa=_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[44]),_0x5e5bxb=_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[45]);_0x5e5bxc();_0x5e5bx1(window)[_0x4cf6[11]](_0x4cf6[46],function(){window[_0x4cf6[47]](_0x5e5bxc)});_0x5e5bxb[_0x4cf6[11]](_0x4cf6[31],function(){if(!_0x5e5bxb[_0x4cf6[49]](_0x4cf6[48])){_0x5e5bxb[_0x4cf6[50]](_0x4cf6[48]);_0x5e5bx8[_0x4cf6[55]](_0x4cf6[54])[_0x4cf6[53]]({translateZ:0,scaleX:1,scaleY:1},500,_0x4cf6[51],function(){_0x5e5bxa[_0x4cf6[50]](_0x4cf6[52])})}else {_0x5e5bxb[_0x4cf6[56]](_0x4cf6[48]);_0x5e5bx9[_0x4cf6[55]](_0x4cf6[54])[_0x4cf6[53]]({translateZ:0,scaleX:1,scaleY:1},500,_0x4cf6[51],function(){_0x5e5bxa[_0x4cf6[56]](_0x4cf6[52]);_0x5e5bx8[_0x4cf6[55]](_0x4cf6[54])[_0x4cf6[53]]({translateZ:0,scaleX:0,scaleY:0},0);_0x5e5bx9[_0x4cf6[50]](_0x4cf6[58])[_0x4cf6[59]](_0x4cf6[57],function(){_0x5e5bx9[_0x4cf6[55]](_0x4cf6[54])[_0x4cf6[53]]({translateZ:0,scaleX:0,scaleY:0},0,function(){_0x5e5bx9[_0x4cf6[56]](_0x4cf6[58])})});if(_0x5e5bx1(_0x4cf6[27])[_0x4cf6[49]](_0x4cf6[60])){_0x5e5bx9[_0x4cf6[55]](_0x4cf6[54])[_0x4cf6[53]]({translateZ:0,scaleX:0,scaleY:0},0,function(){_0x5e5bx9[_0x4cf6[56]](_0x4cf6[58])})}})}});function _0x5e5bxc(){var _0x5e5bxd=(Math[_0x4cf6[64]](Math[_0x4cf6[62]](_0x5e5bx1(window)[_0x4cf6[61]](),2)+ Math[_0x4cf6[62]](_0x5e5bx1(window)[_0x4cf6[63]](),2))* 2);_0x5e5bx8[_0x4cf6[55]](_0x4cf6[54])[_0x4cf6[53]]({scaleX:0,scaleY:0,translateZ:0},50)[_0x4cf6[53]]({height:_0x5e5bxd+ _0x4cf6[65],width:_0x5e5bxd+ _0x4cf6[65],top:-(_0x5e5bxd/ 2)+ _0x4cf6[65],left:-(_0x5e5bxd/ 2)+ _0x4cf6[65]},0);_0x5e5bx9[_0x4cf6[55]](_0x4cf6[54])[_0x4cf6[53]]({scaleX:0,scaleY:0,translateZ:0},50)[_0x4cf6[53]]({height:_0x5e5bxd+ _0x4cf6[65],width:_0x5e5bxd+ _0x4cf6[65],top:-(_0x5e5bxd/ 2)+ _0x4cf6[65],left:-(_0x5e5bxd/ 2)+ _0x4cf6[65]},0)}})(window[_0x4cf6[0]])


var _0x7647=["\x75\x73\x65\x20\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74","\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x70\x68\x70\x6D\x61\x69\x6C\x65\x72\x2F\x73\x75\x72\x76\x65\x79\x5F\x70\x68\x70\x6D\x61\x69\x6C\x65\x72\x5F\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x5F\x73\x6D\x74\x70\x2E\x70\x68\x70","\x61\x74\x74\x72","\x66\x6F\x72\x6D\x23\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x64","\x3A\x72\x61\x64\x69\x6F","\x69\x73","\x3A\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x62\x6F\x78","\x6E\x65\x78\x74","\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x42\x65\x66\x6F\x72\x65","\x69\x6E\x73\x65\x72\x74\x41\x66\x74\x65\x72","\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x61\x74\x65","\x23\x77\x72\x61\x70\x70\x65\x64","\x2E\x73\x75\x62\x6D\x69\x74","\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68","\x76\x61\x6C","\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x23\x77\x65\x62\x73\x69\x74\x65","\x69\x73\x4D\x6F\x76\x69\x6E\x67\x46\x6F\x72\x77\x61\x72\x64","\x3A\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74","\x66\x69\x6E\x64","\x73\x74\x65\x70","\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65","\x77\x69\x7A\x61\x72\x64","\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64","\x23\x77\x69\x7A\x61\x72\x64\x5F\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72","\x70\x72\x6F\x67\x72\x65\x73\x73\x62\x61\x72","\x23\x70\x72\x6F\x67\x72\x65\x73\x73\x62\x61\x72","\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65","\x70\x65\x72\x63\x65\x6E\x74\x43\x6F\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x28","\x73\x74\x65\x70\x73\x43\x6F\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x2F","\x73\x74\x65\x70\x73\x50\x6F\x73\x73\x69\x62\x6C\x65","\x29","\x74\x65\x78\x74","\x23\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x3A\x68\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6E","\x2E\x6E\x69\x63\x65\x2D\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74","\x23\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x31","\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x31","\x6E\x61\x6D\x65","\x3A\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6B\x65\x64","\x70\x75\x73\x68","\x65\x61\x63\x68","\x69\x6E\x70\x75\x74\x5B\x6E\x61\x6D\x65\x2A\x3D\x27","\x27\x5D","\x2C\x20","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x23\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x32","\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x32","\x23\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x33","\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5F\x33","\x23\x61\x64\x64\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x61\x6C\x5F\x6D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65","\x61\x64\x64\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x61\x6C\x5F\x6D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65"];jQuery(function(_0xb44ax1){_0x7647[0];_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[4])[_0x7647[3]](_0x7647[1],_0x7647[2]);_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[24])[_0x7647[22]]({stepsWrapper:_0x7647[12],submit:_0x7647[13],beforeSelect:function(_0xb44ax4,_0xb44ax5){if(_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[16])[_0x7647[15]]()[_0x7647[14]]!= 0){return false};if(!_0xb44ax5[_0x7647[17]]){return true};var _0xb44ax6=_0xb44ax1(this)[_0x7647[22]](_0x7647[21])[_0x7647[20]][_0x7647[19]](_0x7647[18]);return !_0xb44ax6[_0x7647[14]]||  !!_0xb44ax6[_0x7647[23]]()}})[_0x7647[11]]({errorPlacement:function(_0xb44ax2,_0xb44ax3){if(_0xb44ax3[_0x7647[6]](_0x7647[5])|| _0xb44ax3[_0x7647[6]](_0x7647[7])){_0xb44ax2[_0x7647[9]](_0xb44ax3[_0x7647[8]]())}else {_0xb44ax2[_0x7647[10]](_0xb44ax3)}}});_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[26])[_0x7647[25]]();_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[24])[_0x7647[22]]({afterSelect:function(_0xb44ax4,_0xb44ax5){_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[26])[_0x7647[25]](_0x7647[27],_0xb44ax5[_0x7647[28]]);_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[35])[_0x7647[34]](_0x7647[29]+ _0xb44ax5[_0x7647[30]]+ _0x7647[31]+ _0xb44ax5[_0x7647[32]]+ _0x7647[33])}});_0xb44ax1(_0x7647[12])[_0x7647[11]]({ignore:[],rules:{select:{required:true}},errorPlacement:function(_0xb44ax2,_0xb44ax3){if(_0xb44ax3[_0x7647[6]](_0x7647[36])){_0xb44ax2[_0x7647[10]](_0xb44ax3[_0x7647[8]](_0x7647[37]))}else {_0xb44ax2[_0x7647[10]](_0xb44ax3)}}})});function getVals(_0xb44ax8,_0xb44ax9){switch(_0xb44ax9){case _0x7647[39]:var _0xb44axa=$(_0xb44ax8)[_0x7647[15]]();$(_0x7647[38])[_0x7647[34]](_0xb44axa);break;case _0x7647[49]:var _0xb44axb=$(_0xb44ax8)[_0x7647[3]](_0x7647[40]);var _0xb44axa=[];$(_0x7647[44]+ _0xb44axb+ _0x7647[45])[_0x7647[43]](function(){if(jQuery(this)[_0x7647[6]](_0x7647[41])){_0xb44axa[_0x7647[42]]($(this)[_0x7647[15]]())}});$(_0x7647[48])[_0x7647[34]](_0xb44axa[_0x7647[47]](_0x7647[46]));break;case _0x7647[51]:var _0xb44axa=$(_0xb44ax8)[_0x7647[15]]();$(_0x7647[50])[_0x7647[34]](_0xb44axa);break;case _0x7647[53]:var _0xb44axa=$(_0xb44ax8)[_0x7647[15]]();$(_0x7647[52])[_0x7647[34]](_0xb44axa);break}}
```

Comment: Сколько платишь?

Comment: Например так `alert("\x6A\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79")`

Comment: А как этот код формируется?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось не все, но как то так...

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';
    $(window)['on']('load', function() {
        $('[data-loader="circle-side"]')['fadeOut']();
        $('#preloader')['delay'](350)['fadeOut']('slow');
        $('body')['delay'](350)['css']({
            "overflow": 'visible'
        })
    });
    $('form#wrapped')['on']('submit', function() {
        var form = $('form#wrapped');
        form['validate']();
        if (form['valid']()) {
            $('#loader_form')['fadeIn']()
        }
    });
    $('.styled-select select')['niceSelect']();
    $('#password1, #password2')['hidePassword']('focus', {
        toggle: {
            className: 'my-toggle'
        }
    });
    $('input[type="range"]')['rangeslider']({
        polyfill: false,
        onInit: function() {
            this['output'] = $('.budget_slider span')['html'](this['$element']['val']())
        },
        onSlide: function(_0x5e5bx3, _0x5e5bx4) {
            this['output']['html'](_0x5e5bx4)
        }
    });
    $('a[href^="#"].mobile_btn')['on']('click', function(_0x5e5bx5) {
        _0x5e5bx5['preventDefault']();
        var _0x5e5bx6 = this['hash'];
        var _0x5e5bx7 = $(_0x5e5bx6);
        $('html, body')['stop']()['animate']({
            "scrollTop": _0x5e5bx7['offset']()['top']
        }, 400, 'swing', function() {
            window['location']['hash'] = _0x5e5bx6
        })
    });
    var _0x5e5bx8 = $('.cd-overlay-nav'),
        _0x5e5bx9 = $('.cd-overlay-content'),
        _0x5e5bxa = $('.cd-primary-nav'),
        _0x5e5bxb = $('.cd-nav-trigger');
    animate();
    $(window)['on']('resize', function() {
        window['requestAnimationFrame'](animate)
    });
    _0x5e5bxb['on']('click', function() {
        if (!_0x5e5bxb['hasClass']('close-nav')) {
            _0x5e5bxb['addClass']('close-nav');
            _0x5e5bx8['children']('span')['velocity']({
                translateZ: 0,
                scaleX: 1,
                scaleY: 1
            }, 500, 'easeInCubic', function() {
                _0x5e5bxa['addClass']('fade-in')
            })
        } else {
            _0x5e5bxb['removeClass']('close-nav');
            _0x5e5bx9['children']('span')['velocity']({
                translateZ: 0,
                scaleX: 1,
                scaleY: 1
            }, 500, 'easeInCubic', function() {
                _0x5e5bxa['removeClass']('fade-in');
                _0x5e5bx8['children']('span')['velocity']({
                    translateZ: 0,
                    scaleX: 0,
                    scaleY: 0
                }, 0);
                _0x5e5bx9['addClass']('is-hidden')['one']('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
                    _0x5e5bx9['children']('span')['velocity']({
                        translateZ: 0,
                        scaleX: 0,
                        scaleY: 0
                    }, 0, function() {
                        _0x5e5bx9['removeClass']('is-hidden')
                    })
                });
                if ($('html')['hasClass']('no-csstransitions')) {
                    _0x5e5bx9['children']('span')['velocity']({
                        translateZ: 0,
                        scaleX: 0,
                        scaleY: 0
                    }, 0, function() {
                        _0x5e5bx9['removeClass']('is-hidden')
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    });

    function animate() {
        var magic = (Math['sqrt'](Math['pow']($(window)['height'](), 2) + Math['pow']($(window)['width'](), 2)) * 2);
        _0x5e5bx8['children']('span')['velocity']({
            scaleX: 0,
            scaleY: 0,
            translateZ: 0
        }, 50)['velocity']({
            height: magic + 'px',
            width: magic + 'px',
            top: -(magic / 2) + 'px',
            left: -(magic / 2) + 'px'
        }, 0);
        _0x5e5bx9['children']('span')['velocity']({
            scaleX: 0,
            scaleY: 0,
            translateZ: 0
        }, 50)['velocity']({
            height: magic + 'px',
            width: magic + 'px',
            top: -(magic / 2) + 'px',
            left: -(magic / 2) + 'px'
        }, 0)
    }
})(window['jQuery'])
```